# Android change dpi screen programmatically

Tags: c#, android, screen, resolution, dpi

I have an app develop for a Tablet Model resolution 1920x1200 and hdpi 1,5. But unfortunately actually I have tablets with resolution 1920x1200 and dpi 1,7. I could change the dpi with de developer options (option less widht : 720->800) I could change the dpi via adb too.

When I put the dpi on 1,5 the app looks exactly like original tablet

The problem I have is when I reboot this params adb or developer options revert to original.

The question is...I could change the dpi of the screen programmatically like a service on reboot?

I investigate with DisplayMetrics.SetTo but it doesn't work.